# How to have a set of elements easily accessible by different functions without having to declare them in each scope and without using globals?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a form containing about 20 inputs, which I use to store values which are later to be manipulated by some Javascript functions:

```
<input id="input_1" value="x" type="hidden"/>
<input id="input_2" value="y" type="hidden"/>
<input id="input_3" value="z" type="hidden"/>
<!--- ... --->
```

I also have a number of Javascript functions, all of which make use of such values (some may use just a few, but most functions will use all of them), manipulating the values themselves and doing other stuff as well, for example changing some properties of the elements containing them:

```
function foo() {
    var input_input_1 = document.getElementById('input_1')
    var input_input_2 = document.getElementById('input_2')
    var input_input_3 = document.getElementById('input_3')

    input_input_3.value = input_input_1.value + input_input_2.value

    input_input_3.style.visibility = 'visible'

    // ...
}
```

Now the end result is that I ended up with a lot of functions redeclaring the very same elements at the top. Although this might be ok on a technical level, I'm concerned about how unmantainable this has become. The actual code is of course more complex, and I often have to introduce new elements to be handled within the functions, which in turn forces me to change a lot of functions and make them "fetch" the new elements at the start.

So I'd rather have a single snippet of code "preloading" all of the element within the scope of the functions needing them at once (somehow, somewhere), to keep things tidy and to make it easy to add new elements for the functions to use by allowing me to change a single snippet of code.

What I've tried:

- Creating a function `preload_elements()`, "fetching" all of the elements I need to handle within the functions and declaring them as globals, calling the function itself using `<body>`'s `onLoad()` event. This puts all of the elements within the scope of each function of course, however research has told me that globals, much as in other languages, are discouraged in Javascript too.
- I thought of having a function `fetch_elements()` returning an array containing all the elements I need to handle within the functions, and having each function retrieve the elements by calling `fetch_elements()` at the start of the function itself, however since there's no such thing as associative arrays in Javascript, and since having the elements stored within an indexed array would just make me go crazy referencing each element by number, this is a no-no too.

What would be a clever way of accomplishing what I'm after?

Comment: _"there's no such thing as associative arrays in Javascript"_ There is, we call them Objects: `const elems = { inputs: [...], buttons: { cancel: ..., validate: ... }`

Comment: @blex Thanks for bringing that up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid globals would be to put your script into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), eg:

```
(() => {
  var input_input_1 = document.getElementById('input_1')
  // ...
  function foo() {
    // reference input_input_1 here
  }
  function bar() {
    // reference input_input_1 here
  }
  // other logic here
})();
```

But there's an even better way than the above which is much less repetitive:

> however since there's no such thing as associative arrays in Javascript, and since having the elements stored within an indexed array would just make me go crazy referencing each element by number, this is a no-no too.

JavaScript has objects, which are maps of strings to values. Here, it could be a map of the input ID to the associated element.

```
(() => {
  const inputs = {};
  for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('form input')) {
    inputs[input.id] = input;
  }
  // ...
  function foo() {
    // reference inputs.input_1 here
  }
  function bar() {
    // reference inputs.input_1 here
  }
  // other logic here
})();
```

If you have multiple forms on the page, or some inputs inside the form you want to exclude from the `inputs` object, you'll have to tweak the selector string above `form input` appropriately.

No need for a separate function that fetches the elements - just fetch the elements *once* at the start of the IIFE.

Comment: Thank you. Neat solution indeed. I'm curious how this would compare to having, for example, a function building and returning an object containing all of the elements (since I've just learned from the comments that this could be a way to resemble the associative arrays I was after). Anything particularly against that technique? Either way I'm gonna go with your solution, which for sure looks easier to use, it's just that I'm a design pattern and Javascript rookie and I'm trying to learn something :). Thank you again!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing - making an object containing all the elements - except without the function. If you wanted to make it into a function: `const getElms = () => { const inputs = {};
  for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('form input')) {
    inputs[input.id] = input;
  } return inputs;` - but there's not much point since you only need to fetch the inputs once, not over and over again.

Comment: Indeed, I was just brainstorming and I thought that in some cases, maybe, you'd be forced into having your script *not* enclosed in that IIFE and that in that case you'd be forced to use the "regular function" technique (passing back the object etc). But I have no idea really, again, just brainstorming :). Both solutions seem to fit my case, and this one is certainly easier to implement, I was just curious as to whether the other would be considered bad practice for some reason, in case I need to use something like that.

Comment: Hrm, you might want a function version of it if the elements get dynamically created/deleted, in which case retrieving them all ahead of time might not work. Yeah, ideally every time you write a script, you'd want to put it into an IIFE, or even better, bundle it with modules to make it more maintainable as it gets larger

Comment: I see, good point. And I'll look into modules, as in fact this project is already growing a little bit too large to have everything packed into a single script maybe. Thanks for the insights!